# how to connect to Bluetooth Low Energy Device

Tags: android

hi everyone i am working on android app which requires connecting to ble device and sending data over ble. i have tried scanning and displaying the scanned devices on a list which works fine. the problem is with connecting to the scanned device. here is the part of my main activity code.

```
public class main_activity extends Activity implements   BluetoothLeUart.Callback{
public ImageButton fabbutton;
Activity activity;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ArrayList<String> liste,devicedata;
private ListView list;
public EditText input;
String name,address,Devicename,Deviceaddress,datadevicename;
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
public static String SelectedDeviceName;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> dev;
private Handler mHandler;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
BluetoothLeUart uart = new BluetoothLeUart(this);
public static BluetoothDevice device;
private BluetoothGatt mGatt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);

    fabbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fabbutton);
    activity = this;
    mHandler = new Handler();
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    scanLeDevice(true);
    mActionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#727272'>Board List</font>"));
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    liste = new ArrayList<String>();
    liste.clear();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(list.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, liste);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

     // On  Click Listener for Paired BLE Device List
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            SelectedDeviceName = list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            String[] splitString = SelectedDeviceName.split("  ");
            Devicename = splitString[0];
            Deviceaddress = splitString[1];
            device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(Deviceaddress);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),device.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), true, gattCallback);
            uart.connectFirstAvailable();// this is where i start connecting process.

        }
    });
```

here is the code of my BluetoothLeUart class

```
public class BluetoothLeUart extends BluetoothGattCallback implements BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback {
public String mDeviceAddress;
// UUIDs for UART service and associated characteristics.
public static UUID UART_UUID = UUID.fromString("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");
public static UUID TX_UUID   = UUID.fromString("6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");
public static UUID RX_UUID   = UUID.fromString("6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");

// UUID for the UART BTLE client characteristic which is necessary for notifications.
public static UUID CLIENT_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

// UUIDs for the Device Information service and associated characeristics.
public static UUID DIS_UUID       = UUID.fromString("0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
public static UUID DIS_MANUF_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
public static UUID DIS_MODEL_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
public static UUID DIS_HWREV_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
public static UUID DIS_SWREV_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

// Internal UART state.
private Context context;
private WeakHashMap<Callback, Object> callbacks;
private BluetoothAdapter adapter;
private BluetoothGatt gatt;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic tx;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic rx;
private boolean connectFirst;
private boolean writeInProgress; // Flag to indicate a write is currently in progress

// Device Information state.
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic disManuf;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic disModel;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic disHWRev;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic disSWRev;
private boolean disAvailable;

// Queues for characteristic read (synchronous)
private Queue<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> readQueue;

// Interface for a BluetoothLeUart client to be notified of UART actions.
public interface Callback {
    public void onConnected(BluetoothLeUart uart);
    public void onConnectFailed(BluetoothLeUart uart);
    public void onDisconnected(BluetoothLeUart uart);
    public void onReceive(BluetoothLeUart uart, BluetoothGattCharacteristic rx);
    public void onDeviceFound(BluetoothDevice device);
    public void onDeviceInfoAvailable();
}

public BluetoothLeUart(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.callbacks = new WeakHashMap<Callback, Object>();
    this.adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    this.gatt = null;
    this.tx = null;
    this.rx = null;
    this.disManuf = null;
    this.disModel = null;
    this.disHWRev = null;
    this.disSWRev = null;
    this.disAvailable = false;
    this.connectFirst = false;
    this.writeInProgress = false;
    this.readQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();
}

// Return instance of BluetoothGatt.
public BluetoothGatt getGatt() {
    return gatt;
}

// Return true if connected to UART device, false otherwise.
public boolean isConnected() {
    return (tx != null && rx != null);
}

public String getDeviceInfo() {
    if (tx == null || !disAvailable ) {
        // Do nothing if there is no connection.
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Manufacturer : " + disManuf.getStringValue(0) + "\n");
    sb.append("Model        : " + disModel.getStringValue(0) + "\n");
    sb.append("Firmware     : " + disSWRev.getStringValue(0) + "\n");
    return sb.toString();
};

public boolean deviceInfoAvailable() { return disAvailable; }

// Send data to connected UART device.
public void send(byte[] data) {
    if (tx == null || data == null || data.length == 0) {
        // Do nothing if there is no connection or message to send.
        return;
    }
    // Update TX characteristic value.  Note the setValue overload that takes a byte array must be used.
    tx.setValue(data);
    writeInProgress = true; // Set the write in progress flag
    gatt.writeCharacteristic(tx);
    // ToDo: Update to include a timeout in case this goes into the weeds
    while (writeInProgress); // Wait for the flag to clear in onCharacteristicWrite
}


public void registerCallback(Callback callback) {
    callbacks.put(callback, null);
}
public void unregisterCallback(Callback callback) {
    callbacks.remove(callback);
}

// Disconnect to a device if currently connected.
public void disconnect() {
    if (gatt != null) {
        gatt.disconnect();
    }
    gatt = null;
    tx = null;
    rx = null;
}

// Stop any in progress UART device scan.
public void stopScan() {
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.stopLeScan(this);
    }
}

// Start scanning for BLE UART devices.  Registered callback's onDeviceFound method will be called
// when devices are found during scanning.
public void startScan() {
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.startLeScan(this);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Entered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

// Connect to the first available UART device.
public void connectFirstAvailable() {

    // Disconnect to any connected device.
    disconnect();
    // Stop any in progress device scan.
    stopScan();
    // Start scan and connect to first available device.
    connectFirst = true;
    startScan();

}

// Handlers for BluetoothGatt and LeScan events.
@Override
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
    super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
    if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            // Connected to device, start discovering services.
            if (!gatt.discoverServices()) {
                // Error starting service discovery.
                connectFailure();
            }
        }
        else {
            // Error connecting to device.
            connectFailure();
        }
    }
    else if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
        // Disconnected, notify callbacks of disconnection.
        rx = null;
        tx = null;
        notifyOnDisconnected(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
    super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
    // Notify connection failure if service discovery failed.
    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_FAILURE) {
        connectFailure();
        return;
    }

    // Save reference to each UART characteristic.
    tx = gatt.getService(UART_UUID).getCharacteristic(TX_UUID);
    rx = gatt.getService(UART_UUID).getCharacteristic(RX_UUID);


    // Setup notifications on RX characteristic changes (i.e. data received).
    // First call setCharacteristicNotification to enable notification.
    if (!gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(rx, true)) {
        // Stop if the characteristic notification setup failed.
        connectFailure();
        return;
    }
    // Next update the RX characteristic's client descriptor to enable notifications.
    BluetoothGattDescriptor desc = rx.getDescriptor(CLIENT_UUID);
    if (desc == null) {
        // Stop if the RX characteristic has no client descriptor.
        connectFailure();
        return;
    }
    desc.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    if (!gatt.writeDescriptor(desc)) {
        // Stop if the client descriptor could not be written.
        connectFailure();
        return;
    }
    // Notify of connection completion.
    notifyOnConnected(this);
}

@Override
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
    notifyOnReceive(this, characteristic);
}

@Override
public void onCharacteristicRead (BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
    super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);

    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        //Log.w("DIS", characteristic.getStringValue(0));
        // Check if there is anything left in the queue
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic nextRequest = readQueue.poll();
        if(nextRequest != null){
            // Send a read request for the next item in the queue
            gatt.readCharacteristic(nextRequest);
        }
        else {
            // We've reached the end of the queue
            disAvailable = true;
            notifyOnDeviceInfoAvailable();
        }
    }
    else {
        //Log.w("DIS", "Failed reading characteristic " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
    super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);

    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        // Log.d(TAG,"Characteristic write successful");
    }
    writeInProgress = false;
}

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "onLe Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (!parseUUIDs(scanRecord).contains(UART_UUID)) {
                    return;
                }
                // Notify registered callbacks of found device.
                notifyOnDeviceFound(device);
                // Connect to first found device if required.
                if (connectFirst) {

                    // Stop scanning for devices.

                    // Prevent connections to future found devices.

                    if (mDeviceAddress.equals(device.getAddress())) {
                        stopScan();
                        connectFirst = false;
                        // Connect to device.
                        gatt = device.connectGatt(context, true, this);
                    }

                }
            }


// Private functions to simplify the notification of all callbacks of a certain event.
private void notifyOnConnected(BluetoothLeUart uart) {
    for (Callback cb : callbacks.keySet()) {
        if (cb != null) {
            cb.onConnected(uart);
        }
    }
}

private void notifyOnConnectFailed(BluetoothLeUart uart) {
    for (Callback cb : callbacks.keySet()) {
        if (cb != null) {
            cb.onConnectFailed(uart);
        }
    }
}

private void notifyOnDisconnected(BluetoothLeUart uart) {
    for (Callback cb : callbacks.keySet()) {
        if (cb != null) {
            cb.onDisconnected(uart);
        }
    }
}

private void notifyOnReceive(BluetoothLeUart uart, BluetoothGattCharacteristic rx) {
    for (Callback cb : callbacks.keySet()) {
        if (cb != null ) {
            cb.onReceive(uart, rx);
        }
    }
}

private void notifyOnDeviceFound(BluetoothDevice device) {
    for (Callback cb : callbacks.keySet()) {
        if (cb != null) {
            cb.onDeviceFound(device);
        }
    }
}

private void notifyOnDeviceInfoAvailable() {
    for (Callback cb : callbacks.keySet()) {
        if (cb != null) {
            cb.onDeviceInfoAvailable();
        }
    }
}

// Notify callbacks of connection failure, and reset connection state.
private void connectFailure() {
    rx = null;
    tx = null;
    notifyOnConnectFailed(this);
}


private List<UUID> parseUUIDs(final byte[] advertisedData) {
    List<UUID> uuids = new ArrayList<UUID>();

    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < (advertisedData.length - 2)) {
        int len = advertisedData[offset++];
        if (len == 0)
            break;

        int type = advertisedData[offset++];
        switch (type) {
            case 0x02: // Partial list of 16-bit UUIDs
            case 0x03: // Complete list of 16-bit UUIDs
                while (len > 1) {
                    int uuid16 = advertisedData[offset++];
                    uuid16 += (advertisedData[offset++] << 8);
                    len -= 2;
                    uuids.add(UUID.fromString(String.format("%08x-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", uuid16)));
                }
                break;
            case 0x06:// Partial list of 128-bit UUIDs
            case 0x07:// Complete list of 128-bit UUIDs
                // Loop through the advertised 128-bit UUID's.
                while (len >= 16) {
                    try {
                        // Wrap the advertised bits and order them.
                        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(advertisedData, offset++, 16).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                        long mostSignificantBit = buffer.getLong();
                        long leastSignificantBit = buffer.getLong();
                        uuids.add(new UUID(leastSignificantBit,
                                mostSignificantBit));
                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        // Defensive programming.
                        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                        continue;
                    } finally {
                        // Move the offset to read the next uuid.
                        offset += 15;
                        len -= 16;
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                offset += (len - 1);
                break;
        }
    }
    return uuids;
}
```

}

here is the code of my BluetoothLeService class

```
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
private final static String TAG = BluetoothLeService.class.getSimpleName();

private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
public  BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
private  int mConnectionState =STATE_DISCONNECTED;

private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";

// UUIDs for UART service and associated characteristics.
public static UUID UART_UUID = UUID.fromString("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");
public static UUID TX_UUID   = UUID.fromString("6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");
public static UUID RX_UUID   = UUID.fromString("6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");

// UUID for the UART BTLE client characteristic which is necessary for notifications.
public static UUID CLIENT_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

// UUIDs for the Device Information service and associated characeristics.
public static UUID DIS_UUID       = UUID.fromString("0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
public static UUID DIS_MANUF_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
public static UUID DIS_MODEL_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
public static UUID DIS_HWREV_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
public static UUID DIS_SWREV_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");


// Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
// connection change and services discovered.
public  final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        String intentAction;
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Log.i("STATE CONNECTED", "OK");
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            Log.i("STATE CONNECTED BROADCAST SENT - DISCOVERING SERVICES", "OK");
            // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
            Log.i("AFTER DISCOVER SERVICES", "OK");

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Log.i("STATE DISCONNECTED", "OK");
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            Log.i("STATE DISCONNECTED BROADCAST SENT", "OK");
        }

        if(mConnectionState==123334){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            Log.i("GATT SUCCESS - SERVICES DISCOVERED", "OK");
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
    }
};

private  void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    Log.i("INTENT SENT", "OK");
}

private  void broadcastUpdate(final String action, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

    // For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
    final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
    if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
        for(byte byteChar : data)
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public  BluetoothLeService getService() {
        return BluetoothLeService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    close();
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

public boolean initialize() {
    // For API level 18 and above, get a reference to BluetoothAdapter through
    // BluetoothManager.
    if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
        mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize BluetoothManager.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to obtain a BluetoothAdapter.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

    public boolean connect(final String address) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
        return false;
    }

    // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
    if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
            && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
        if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }
    // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
    // parameter to false.
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
    mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
    return true;
}


public void disconnect() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
}


public void close() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.close();
    mBluetoothGatt = null;
}


public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
}


public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                          boolean enabled) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

}


public List<BluetoothGattService> getSupportedGattServices() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) return null;

    return mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
}
```

}

Comment: can anyone help me with this.

Comment: when i run the application the program executes till the startScan() function in BluetoothLeUart and the toast message in that function is displayed. nothing happens after that. i was expecting onLeScan function to execute and later on the call back functions to execute which doesnot happen. please help me on this..

Answer (score 0):

What is the target version of `targetSdkVersion`. I had similar issue and changed `build.gradle` to

```
defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.XXX.XXXr"
      minSdkVersion 21
      targetSdkVersion 22
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
}
```

It solved the problem, but I have some others needs to be solved...

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Adafruit Feather BLE) the following worked

```
public static String LOG_TAG = "Adafruit Ind";

public static UUID UART_UUID      = UUID.fromString("6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e");
public static UUID TX_UUID        = UUID.fromString("6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e");
public static UUID RX_UUID        = UUID.fromString("6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e");
public static UUID CLIENT_UUID    = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
public static UUID DIS_UUID       = UUID.fromString("000001530-1212-EFDE-1523-785FEABCD123");
public static UUID DIS_MANUF_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002A29-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
public static UUID DIS_MODEL_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002A24-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
public static UUID DIS_HWREV_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002A26-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
public static UUID DIS_SWREV_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002A28-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```